# Wrapper function for sed that takes regex search/replace string as parameters

Tags: bash, shell, sed, sh

I'm trying to create a sed wrapper that first checks if the file exists, if it does, run with the specified parameters. e.g.:

```
sed_wrapper 's/replace this/with this/g' test_file.txt
```

My attempt works fine if there are no spaces in the regex, but as soon as spaces are added it breaks.
To generalize, how can I take a function's parameter that contains spaces and quotations and run it as a command within the function?

The script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# ./test_script.sh

sed_wrapper() {
    ALL_PARAMETERS=($@)
    ALL_PARAMETERS_LENGTH=${#ALL_PARAMETERS[@]}
    PARAMETER_FILE=${ALL_PARAMETERS[$ALL_PARAMETERS_LENGTH_-1]}
    PARAMETER_REGEX=${ALL_PARAMETERS[@]:0:$ALL_PARAMETERS_LENGTH-1}

    echo "ALL_PARAMETERS: $ALL_PARAMETERS"
    echo "-------------------------------"
    if [ -f "$PARAMETER_FILE" ] ; then
        sed $PARAMETER_REGEX $PARAMETER_FILE
    fi
}

sed_wrapper 's/#REPLACETHIS/\0--->simple_example/g' test_file.txt
echo "************************************************************"
sed_wrapper 's/#REPLACETHIS/\0--->complex example/g' test_file.txt
echo "************************************************************"
sed_wrapper "'s/#REPLACETHIS/\0--->quotation_example/g'" test_file.txt
```

Contents of test_file.txt:

```
#REPLACETHIS
```

Output of running ./test_script.sh:

```
ALL_PARAMETERS: s/#REPLACETHIS/\0--->simple_example/g test_file.txt
-------------------------------
#REPLACETHIS--->simple_example
************************************************************
ALL_PARAMETERS: s/#REPLACETHIS/\0--->complex example/g test_file.txt
-------------------------------
sed: -e expression #1, char 28: unterminated `s' command
************************************************************
ALL_PARAMETERS: 's/#REPLACETHIS/\0--->quotation_example/g' test_file.txt
-------------------------------
sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `''
```

Expected output of running ./test_script.sh:

```
ALL_PARAMETERS: s/#REPLACETHIS/\0--->simple_example/g test_file.txt
-------------------------------
#REPLACETHIS--->simple_example
************************************************************
ALL_PARAMETERS: s/#REPLACETHIS/\0--->complex example/g test_file.txt
-------------------------------
#REPLACETHIS--->complex example
************************************************************
ALL_PARAMETERS: 's/#REPLACETHIS/\0--->quotation_example/g' test_file.txt
-------------------------------
#REPLACETHIS--->quotation_example
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When running the final sed command, you can use the original parameters:

Use the quoted $@. It will make sure all parameters are quoted properly.

```
sed "$@"
```

Instead of:

```
sed $PARAMETER_REGEX $PARAMETER_FILE
```

There are simpler constructs in bash to perform this task of creating 'silent_sed'. (Logging statement removed from function for simplicity)

```
sed_wrapper() {
    local PARAMETER_FILE=${@:#$}
    if [ -f "$PARAMETER_FILE" ] ; then
        sed "$@"
    fi
}
```

Comment: @user2162449 : In addition, I think it also makes sense to quote the variables inside the sed_wrapper, i.e. `ALL_PARAMETERS=("$@")` and `PARAMETER_FILE="${ALL_PARAMETERS[$ALL_PARAMETERS_LENGTH_-1]}"`